# Unix permissions error when working with symbolic link and MySQL installation

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, mysql, symbolic-link

I'm working to install MySQL on one of our servers. I'm the `ec2-user`, and I'm attempting to install in the `ec2-user` home directory, but allowing access to the directory to the `mysql` user.

However, even though initially logging in as `mysql` gives me access to the directory, I can't find a way to get back to it if I leave:

```
-bash-4.1$ whoami
mysql
-bash-4.1$ ls
bin  COPYING  data  docs  include  INSTALL-BINARY  lib  man  my.cnf  my-new.cnf  mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64  mysql-test  README  scripts  share  sql-bench  support-files
-bash-4.1$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/install/mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64
-bash-4.1$ ls -l /usr/local
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 games
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 include
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql mysql 4096 Oct  8  2014 lib64
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 libexec
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   69 Apr 18 13:27 mysql -> /home/ec2-user/install/mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 6 mysql mysql 4096 Oct  8  2014 share
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Jan  6  2012 src
-bash-4.1$ cd /usr/local/mysql
-bash: cd: /usr/local/mysql: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be performing the entire installation as the `mysql` user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/local/mysql` links to `/home/ec2-user/install/mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64`, and while the link itself has the default link permission, we still do not know what the permissions are for `/home/ec2-user/install/mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64`, and I bet that is the source of the issue.

What is the output of `ls -la /home/ec2-user/install/mysql-5.6.24-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64` ? The entry represented by a `.` is what we're interested in. I'm thinking one of these:

- Incorrect owner (and maybe group). Should be set to whatever the mysql process runs as, in this case `mysql`
- Incorrect permissions. Can be many things, but I think it should be 700 (owner can do whatever, nobody else is allowed to touch it)
- A combination of the two above.